# How to use data from a table as a value for another command in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-manager

I have in mind something like this:
Let's say there is a

```
Select Client_name
From Clients_Master_Table
where Client_Name = 'DS_Store';
```

So, here's how to use 'DS_Store' which is given from the table as a value for the command:

As if to do

```
Select DS_Store
From DS_Table;
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM YourTable where CLIENT_NAME IN(SELECT DS_STORE FROM DS_TABLE)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `IN`:

```
Select Client_name
From Clients_Master_Table
where Client_Name IN (Select DS_Store from DS_Table)
```

Comment: But I want take some value from table and reuse this info as a comand

Comment: Is that possible to do it?